# expo ios build failing on fastlane

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to build my expo app for ios (`eas build --platform ios`) but it keeps failing at `fastlane`. My previous build (2 months ago) was successful so I don't know what the problem is now.

Here is the error -

[image]

Here is how my `eas.json` looks like:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 0.53.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {"image": "latest"}
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "appleId": "raxxxxxx",
        "ascAppId": "xxxxxx",
        "appleTeamId": "xxxxxx"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I resolve this?

My app is just a simple one, here is how it is structured:

[image]